# Negotiation on counter offer

Tags: salary, negotiation, raise, career-switch

I have got an good offer from an organization so I resigned, but now my current employer is giving me a counter offer with similar raise but after 2 months and an onsite opportunity which is not there in new employer.

**Facts :**

1. I am the one who is exclusively working on a project and no one else in the organization have knowledge of that project and the project is important.
2. I am consistent performer.
3. Got recently promoted at senior level
4. Handling a team

**Comparison :**

1. Technology wise : my current employer is more advanced
2. Salary wise : new employer is offering the salary from August but current employer is offering same raise from month of October (so 2 months loss in terms of salary).
3. On site opportunity with current employer which is not there with new employer.

**My questions are:**

1. Should I accept the counter offer?
2. Is it okay to believe that they will give me a raise after 2 months, should I take it in written?
3. If I go onsite then there is a policy to stay in current organization for next one year. So will this be a problem in future?

**I am thinking to put following conditions :**

1. Raise salary from August.
2. waive off the policy stating you cant leave organization for one year for me.
3. Current raise shouldn't impact my normal appraisal cycle.

please suggest me over this, what should I do, and what other points should I take into considerations?

**UPDATE**

on site : Work at client site / other branch of company in other country.

Comment: If you choose to stay with your current employer, I would make a condition of your stay that your employment contract be revised to reflect the raise and other benefits they wish to offer you for retaining you in the company. Get it in writing or get packing to the new company.

Comment: My gut is telling me that the 2-month delay in your raise is just 2 months they plan on spending finding your replacement.  If they were serious, it would be immediate.  That's just my impression, though.

Comment: We can't make the call on which job for you to take.  As general policy if it's not in writing it doesn't exist.  If you want exemptions from any policies or follow through on any promises be sure to get them in writing.

Comment: Deciding which offer to take is something that only you can do; please [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/49642/edit) your question to give us something we can help with - e.g. what to ask for, whether to trust your current employer, or how to make the evaluation.  Also, part of your question isn't clear (at least to me): What do you mean by "on-site" - work in the employer's location vs. work from home, or work at a client location instead of your employer's location or ???

Comment: @GreenMatt I have updated about onsite.

Answer (score 3):

Let me offer a cautionary tale from a time when I was in a similar situation many years ago. I had left one employer that I'll call A to join another that I'll call B. After 10 months A still hadn't replaced me and made me an offer to return that dwarfed my then current salary. I liked the work I did with B better than what I'd done with A, so I went to B and told them that I wanted to stay, but the money difference was too much to ignore. My boss with B and his boss both told me that they couldn't quite match the new salary A offered, but they could give me a big raise. The new raise was enough that I was willing to stay (the work was more interesting and B had significantly better benefits). Thus I told A something like "Thanks, but I'll be staying where I am."

The catch was that B claimed they couldn't give me a raise until I'd been through a performance appraisal, which couldn't happen until I'd been there a full year. I got past my one year anniversary and went through the appraisal process and was promised that the big raise would come on my next payday. Then, on the day I was supposed to receive that first pay with the bigger salary I got called into the office of the manager two levels above me - she said that management above her didn't sign off on my big raise, so I was getting what amounted to a cost of living increase.

As a result of the experience above, I recommend that if you  stay with your current employer you insist that your increased salary starts immediately. Also, get it in writing!

Additionally, get in writing any waivers you want from company policy. However, I don't think you are likely to get an increased salary AND a waiver from a commitment to stay at least one year AND to stay on your normal performance appraisal cycle. In fact, I don't even think you should ask for the latter two items.  Ask for the salary increase and accept the other two conditions as your part of staying.  Asking for the waiver for the requirement to stay one year sends the message that you don't really want to stay with your current employer; thus they have no incentive to offer to match (or exceed) the new company's offer.  As for the review cycle: from the company's perspective, you just got a big raise that they likely hadn't planned on; giving them time to absorb that and re-work their plans shows that you understand where they are and what they need. If you can't agree to those conditions, then I recommend that you move to the new company, as it seems you're not happy where you are, and the new salary won't change that.

Answer (score 2):

Never accept counter offers when leaving a position, your current employer knows you are trying to leave, knows you want better pay, better position, etc... they are going to work you to the bone in that 1 year to get as much out of you as possible while also looking for someone to replace you, especially if they have you on contract to stay there for the full year, they will milk you with a huge legal shield as much as possible. Companies do this more so that they can have more time to fill your position and get a set of work done then they do it to keep you around - if you want to look up statistics (everyone's favorite thing) the success rate for people that accept a counter offer over 1 year is less than 95%.

You've made a decision to leave, stick to it, it's that simple. You'll be better for it

Look at it this way, you have a company willing you to pay you properly from the start and another one begging you to stay but still will only 'match' what the other people are happy to pay you and not even right away. If they really wanted you, and just you (not the work you can do for them or time to find someone else) they would would of beat the matched salary happily.

Answer (score -1):

This is a common dilemma.

My understanding is that it is better to stay with your current organization because:

1. You will get a good salary without moving
2. Onsite opportunity
3. Long service period
4. More comfortable work place rather than a new organization

If you are worried about the policy of one year for onsite you should talk with your HR people.

In your position I would accept the counter offer.